# Variable import does not work in views.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-views, django-1.5

Why doesn't the import of a variable outside of a function work in views.py? (ms_fields.py is a file in the same folder)

==== This works: the variable "MS_FIELDS" is imported properly  =============

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext, get_object_or_404 

def current_quote(request):
    from .ms_fields import MS_FIELDS #import within the function
    return render_to_response('mis/current_quote.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

=== **This doesnt work: "local variable 'MS_FIELDS' referenced before assignment"**=====

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext, get_object_or_404 
from .ms_fields import MS_FIELDS  # import at the beginning of the file

def current_quote(request):
    MS_FIELDS = MS_FIELDS 
    return render_to_response('mis/current_quote.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Why is that? Shouldn't the import function make a variable available inside the entire file?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why in heavens name are you using `locals()`?

Comment: Got it from a beginners tutorial and actually don't know what it means... :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the import that doesn't work, it's the assignment. By assigning to MS_FIELDS within the function, you are telling Python it's a local var, which overrides the global name from the import.

I don't understand why you'd do that anyway. Just pass MS_FIELDS to the context explicitly. Using `locals()` is a hack, and not a very nice one.

Comment: MS_FIELDS = MS_FIELDS is just for debugging purposes. If I pass MS_FIELDS to render(), it is lost somewhere on the way to the front end. Therefore, I tried to assign it which causes the error.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you mean. I assumed you were doing that since otherwise it wouldn't be in `locals()` at all. If you did `return render_to_response('mis/current_quote.html', {'MS_FIELDS': MS_FIELDS}, ...)` it should work fine.